# How can a div be forced to remain at a fixed width but expand vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm putting images in divs and setting width of the div to the width of an image that it contains. For example:

```
<div class="img" style="width: 250px;">
<img src="thisIs250pxWide.jpg" alt="something">
<p>Caption text here, assume this text occupies more than 250px when it is all on one line</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that the text, if there's enough of it, stretches the div wider than the specified width.  I want the text to *wrap* at the specified width and stretch the div vertically but not horizontally - the div should remain at the width of the image and the text should wrap to agree with it.  Scrollbars are not acceptable, so `text-overflow` won't help.

In case someone will call this a duplicate of one of the many questions about breaking words, this is not about breaking words.  I don't even mind if long words stick out of the box - I just want normal text wrapping at the spaces between words.

The css is like this:

```
div.img {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 0.5em; margin-right: 0.5em;
border: 0.1em solid #111111;
padding: 0.4em;
}
```

I tried adding css outside the div:

```
<div class="img" id="imgDiv1234" style="width: 250px;">
<img src="thisIs250pxWide.jpg" alt="something">
<p>Caption text here, assume this text occupies more than 250px when it is all on one line</p>
</div>
<style type="text/css">#imgDiv1234 { width: 250px; }</style>
```

(This can't be done in a stylesheet as it is specific to each image.)

Also tried: putting width on the `<p>` as well as the containing div; putting `!important` on the style; setting `display: block` instead of `inline-block`; making sure nothing later in the stylesheet overrules.  Despite everything, the div stretches beyond the specified width if there's enough text.

. . . .

Edit: In case it helps anyone, after this exchange I found out the cause of the problem, it was my CSP header: `style-src 'self';` - this allows a same-domain stylesheet but not inline styles. Changing this to the following allowed my trick to work: `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';`

This is theoretically insecure but the attacks are pretty exotic and don't apply for my application. Absolutely *don't* allow `unsafe-inline` for scripts or anything else but it can be OK for styles if you research and verify it's not exploitable on your site.  Thanks Eevee and Moog

Comment: what you have seems like it should work already; are you sure you don't have other rules interfering?  maybe the `p` has word-wrap off, somehow?

Comment: I agree with @Eevee. There's nothing in your sample code that would prevent this from working. I expect you have `white-space:nowrap` set on the `<p>` or a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you trying `flex` layout. It would simplify your code, and you would not have to specify `width` for every block:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start
}

figure {
  flex: 0 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .4em
}
```

```html
<section>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250" alt="something">
    <figcaption>Caption text here, assume this text occupies more than 250px when it is all on one line</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="something">
    <figcaption>Caption text here, assume this text occupies more than 250px when it is all on one line</figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/50" alt="something">
    <figcaption>Caption text here, assume this text occupies more than 250px when it is all on one line</figcaption>
  </figure>

</section>
```

Comment: Whoa, that flex stuff really works and saves some code.  Thanks Kosh Very!!

Comment: @stephen_789, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the max-width property to set the desired maximum with you like

```
div{
max-width: 200px;
height: auto; 
}
```